# Evaluating variables between single quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have the following bash function:

```
function close() {  osascript -e 'quit app "$1"'; }
```

which sends quit signal to application represented by the first parameter `$1`. The function doesn't work as expected (I think because of the single quotes). I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Remove double quotes and replace single quotes by double quotes.

Comment: `function close() {  osascript -e "quit app \"$1\""; }`  is another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash doesn't perform pattern substitution on single-quoted strings, so if you want your `$1` to be substituted, you'll need to use a double-quoted string.  In order to preserve the double quotes around the `$1`, you'll need to escape them.  Try something like this:

```
function close() {  osascript -e "quit app \"$1\""; }
```